# Rails I18n locale set date format in Rails

Tags: date, internationalization, locale

My environment: rails => 3.0.6, ruby => 1.9.2
I set my locale to Italan. Infact, inside the console

> I18n.locale # =>  :it

My locale file work just fine, but I'cant make my dates display right. For ex. in my console

> Date.current => Sun, 05 Jun 2011

instead of

> 05 Giugno 2011

But if I try other methods it return the right translated output

> helper.number_to_currency(30) # => "30.00 €"

Locale issue occurs only with dates. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date.current => Sun, 05 Jun 2011
```

Won't run your code through the `localizer`, you should use

```
I18n.localize(Date.current)
I18n.l(Date.current)
```

There are also the helper methods in Rails, which will respect the locale, but are only (typically) available in the view, documentation for these lives here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Here's a short excerpt from an IRB session in a Rails 3.0.7 application (I don't have the other locales available)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Date.current
 => Sun, 05 Jun 2011 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > I18n.locale
 => :en 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > I18n.l(Date.current)
 => "2011-06-05" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > I18n.locale = :ru
 => :ru 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > I18n.l(Date.current)
 => I18n::MissingTranslationData: translation missing: ru.date.formats.default
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
I18n.localize(Date.today)
```

or in the view just

```
l(Date.today)
```

Source:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats